# Math.pow vs ** casted as a Decimal in Python?

Tags: python

So I was writing a simple script to demonstrate geometric series convergence.

```
from decimal import *
import math
initial = int(input("a1? "))
r = Decimal(input("r? "))
runtime = int(input("iterations? "))

sum_value=0
for i in range(runtime):
   sum_value+=Decimal(initial * math.pow(r,i))
   print(sum_value)
```

When I use values such as:

```
a1 = 1
r = .2
iterations = 100000
```

I get the convergence to be `1.250000000000000021179302083`

When I replace the line:

```
sum_value+=Decimal(initial * math.pow(r,i))
```

With:

```
sum_value+=Decimal(initial * r ** i)
```

I get a more precise value, `1.250000000000000000000000002`

What exactly is the difference here? From my understanding, it has to do with `math.pow` being a floating point operation, but I would just think that `**` is syntactic sugar for the math power function. If they are indeed different, then why with a precision value of 200, when inputting the following to IDLE:

```
>>> Decimal(.8**500)
Decimal('3.50746621104350087215129555150772856244326043764431058846880005304485310211166734705824986213804838358790165633656170035364028902957755917668691836297512054443359375E-49')
>>> Decimal(math.pow(.8,500))
Decimal('3.50746621104350087215129555150772856244326043764431058846880005304485310211166734705824986213804838358790165633656170035364028902957755917668691836297512054443359375E-49')
```

They seem to be exactly the same. What is happening here?

Comment: Your comparison using `Decimal` is invalid; both results are computed as `float` before being converted.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams okay thank you - so if I switch it so that they aren't casted as decimal (which I did just to get an arbitrary precision value), why is this the case?

Comment: I can't reproduce your result.  If I run your loop with the same values of a1, r, and iterations, I get the same result regardless of whether I do `r**i` or `math.path(r, i)` in the loop.  Can you show a self-contained example where two different results are produced?

Comment: Hi @BrenBarn, thank you for taking the time to try and reproduce. I've created a repl.it [here](https://repl.it/J6bY/0) which shows the exact issue at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is, as you imply, that `math.pow()` converts the inputs to `float`s as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html): "Unlike the built-in ** operator, math.pow() converts both its arguments to type float."

Therefore `math.pow()` also delivers a `float` as answer, independently of whether the input is `Decimal` (or `int`) or whatever. When using numbers that are not exactly representable as a `float`(but is as `Decimal`) you are likely to get a more precise answer using the `**` operator.

This explains why your loop gives a more exact result in case of using `**` since you are working with `Decimal` numbers raised to an integer. In the second case, you are inadvertently using `float`s for both calculations and then converting the result to `Decimal` when the operation is already executed. If you instead work with explicit `Decimal` values you will see the difference:

```
>>> Decimal('.8')**500
Decimal('3.507466211043403874762758796E-49')
>>> Decimal(math.pow(Decimal('.8'), 500))
Decimal('3.50746621104350087215129555150772856244326043764431058846880005304485310211166734705824986213804838358790165633656170035364028902957755917668691836297512054443359375E-49')
```

Thus, in the second case, the `Decimal` value is automatically casted to a `float` and the result is the same as for your example above. In the first case, however, the calculation is executed in the `Decimal` domain and yields a slightly different result.